# Inserting into a table with multiple rows by splitting values from another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables, say table1 and table2.  I want to insert into table2 by splitting the comma separated value in table1.

For ex., assume that in table1:

```
ID          Mac
----        --------------------------------------------------------------------------
9504        11:22:33:44:55:66:77:88, aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff:gg:hh, 99:00:11:22:33:44:55:66
9505        ii:jj:kk:ll:mm:nn:oo:pp, 77:88:99:00:11:22:33:44
```

Then table2 should have:

```
ID          Mac
----        -----------------------
9504        11:22:33:44:55:66:77:88
9504        aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff:gg:hh
9504        99:00:11:22:33:44:55:66
9505        ii:jj:kk:ll:mm:nn:oo:pp
9505        77:88:99:00:11:22:33:44
```

I wrote the following SQL (I don't want to write a stored proc or trigger):

```
INSERT INTO table2 (ID, Mac)

SELECT ID, Left(Mac,23)
FROM table1
WHERE Left(Mac, 23) <> " "

UNION SELECT ID,mid(Mac, 26, 23)
FROM table1
WHERE mid(Mac, 26, 23) <> " "

UNION SELECT ID,mid(Mac, 51, 23)
FROM table1
WHERE mid(Mac, 51, 23) <> " "

UNION SELECT ID,mid(Mac, 75, 23)
FROM table1
WHERE mid(Mac, 75, 23) <> " "

UNION SELECT ID,mid(Mac, 97, 23)
FROM table1
WHERE mid(Mac, 97, 23) <> " ";
```

However I am getting `Syntax Error in FROM clause.` error.

Can you please help me get this fixed.

Thanks in advance!
Vaidya.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response!MS Access

Answer (score 1):

Access seems to be a bit "fussy" about missing `INSERT` and `UNION`.  One workaround would be to assign an explicit alias to the calculated field, make the `UNION` query a subquery, and `SELECT` from the subquery, as in something like:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (ID, Mac)
SELECT ID, X FROM
(SELECT ID, Left(Mac,23) AS X
FROM table1
WHERE Left(Mac, 23) <> " "

UNION SELECT ID,mid(Mac, 26, 23)
FROM table1
WHERE mid(Mac, 26, 23) <> " "

UNION SELECT ID,mid(Mac, 51, 23)
FROM table1
WHERE mid(Mac, 51, 23) <> " "

UNION SELECT ID,mid(Mac, 75, 23)
FROM table1
WHERE mid(Mac, 75, 23) <> " "

UNION SELECT ID,mid(Mac, 97, 23)
FROM table1
WHERE mid(Mac, 97, 23) <> " ");
```

Note that I used `X` instead of `Mac` as the field alias.  When I tried to use `Mac`, Access saw the reference to `Mac` in the calculation as circular.  I suppose you could resolve that by prefixing the reference with the table name.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you want to do all this in one Access query.  Consider creating 5 new queries for your `SELECT` statements, one `UNION` query `UNION`ing the results of those `SELECT` statements, and one `INSERT` query.  Then you should be fine and fully set up for debugging any bad data.